# How to fix point of image in matching image Opencv Android

Tags: android, image, opencv

how to fix point of image in matching image by use rotation template image and return closest value. 
i want to matching template image and input image.
fix point in matching by use rotation template image.
template image is rotated every degree.
return value of matching is float and save in array list.
how to do it by use Open CV android ?

```
private Bitmap MatchImage(int match_method){
    Bitmap bitmapInput = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+"/input_image_pj.bmp");
    Mat matInput = new Mat ( bitmapInput.getHeight(), bitmapInput.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8U);
    Bitmap bitmapCopyInput = bitmapInput.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmapCopyInput, matInput);


    Bitmap  tempImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.image_template);
    Mat matTemp = new Mat ( tempImage.getHeight(), tempImage.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8U);
    Bitmap bitmapCopyTemp = tempImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmapCopyTemp, matTemp);

    rotateTemp(matTemp,1);
    int result_cols = matInput.cols() - matTemp.cols() + 1;
    int result_rows = matInput.rows() - matTemp.rows() + 1;
    Mat matResult = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

    Imgproc.matchTemplate(matInput, matTemp, matResult, match_method);
    Core.normalize(matResult, matResult, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Result : "+matResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(matResult);
    Point matchLoc;
    if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
        matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
    } else {
        matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
    }

    Core.rectangle(matInput, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + matTemp.cols(),
            matchLoc.y + matTemp.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));

    // Save the visualized detection.
    System.out.println("Writing "+ resulfFile);
    Highgui.imwrite(path+resulfFile, matInput);

    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(matInput.cols(),  matInput.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);;
    Utils.matToBitmap(matInput, resultBitmap);
    bitmapInput = resultBitmap;

    return resultBitmap;
}

private Mat rotateTemp(Mat matRotate,int degMore){
    //Rotate Image
    int degrees = 30 + degMore;
    Point center = new Point(matRotate.cols()/2, matRotate.rows()/2);
    Mat rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, degrees, 1.0);
    Imgproc.warpAffine(matRotate, matRotate, rotImage, matRotate.size());
    //mat is rotated    
    return matRotate;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you already tried.

Comment: i have added code top @Im0rtality

Comment: i don't know value in variables matResult.